# Azure HDInsight Spark Cluster - Geo-Replication?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, geo-replication

I have an Azure HDInsight Spark Cluster in WEST US and I want to enable a Geo-Recovery to handle the Disaster Recovery. I don't see any options to the Geo-Recovery for Azure HDInsight Spark Cluster, how do I do it?

Comment: Geo-Recovery is mostly for Storage not for job execution platform. Because you can always retry the failed jobs. You can create an identical cluster as a DR

Comment: Does it mean that we could use the same Storage account for both the actual & passive HDInsight clusters?

Comment: Yes but with a different containers

Comment: What does the different container means? How to setup this?

Comment: As per the Microsoft documentation, if you have enabled Read Geo Redundant on storage account, It only have read access. We need read write access to create the cluster. 

It is not supported to create a cluster with a storage account which is in different region. We do not have any other way to create the cluster in east with storage account in West.

Comment: In this case we need to create two storage accounts in each region.
It is not easy to synch so what you will recommend to have two storage account and both can sync without any maintenance work.

Comment: You can check this-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance